# jquery.selectbox-0.2 issue with ie7 - dropdowns appearing behind elements instead of in front

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using http://code.google.com/p/select-box/ select box jquery plugin so that I can change the appearance of my select boxes.

The plugin is great and works fine except in ie7 where the dropdown lists appear behind any element that they happen to overlap with. It seems to be a known issue but no-one seems to have answered the person who reported it.

I was wondering if anyone could suggest a fix?

the issue can be seen here: http://code.google.com/p/select-box/issues/detail?id=8

thanks for any help :)

Comment: It would be nice to see the page where this is occurring, or a jfiddle.. Can you provide eitheR?

Comment: Without looking at the code I would suggest that you try to change the z-index. Add a higher z-index to the container of the dropdowns. More info: http://brenelz.com/blog/squish-the-internet-explorer-z-index-bug/

Comment: here's a fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/dRW6n/1/

Comment: @Johan I tried using the z-index but it doesn't appear to make any difference. Also I've read in the 2nd link I posted in my OP that the normal z-index fix doesn't work for this code

Comment: is anyone alble to help me with this :(

Comment: Hurray! Hurrah! Woop-woop! this fixes the problem http://www.vancelucas.com/blog/fixing-ie7-z-index-issues-with-jquery/ hope it helps out someone else

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use this solution using this little piece of jquery code, running on dom ready:

```
$(function() {  
    var zIndexNumber = 1000;  
    $('div').each(function() {  
        $(this).css('zIndex', zIndexNumber);  
        zIndexNumber -= 10;  
    });  
});
```

or try to fix the css z-indexing: http://web.enavu.com/snippets/fixing-the-ie7-z-index-issue-internet-explorer-7-z-index/

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/aTUC5/

Answer (score 0):

This can also be solved by giving higher value of z-index to dropdown div and lesser z-index to each div that comes under it and shows text.

Ex:

```
<div id="sbHolder_28376079" class="sbHolder" tabindex="0">
    ...
    </div>
    <div class="div1">
        <div class="div2">
            <div class="div3">
            </div>
        </div> 
    </div>


.sbHolder{z-index : 100;}
.div1{z-index : 90;}
.div2{z-index : 80;}
.div3{z-index : 70;}
```

This applies same logic what is mentioned in above js  but it was breaking my Ui in other part where position absolute and z-index was used.